# How to update the UI without blocking input from user in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asynchronous, xamarin.android

My app is blocked from taking user input when the `listview` is being loaded, backpress and Buttons does not work when this happen.

```
public void OnAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
       Task.Run(() => RunOnUiThread(dodo));
}
```

below code runs when the animation ends

```
public void dodo()
{
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(AdRequest.DeviceIdEmulator).Build();
        adView.LoadAd(adRequest);
        AccessFiles();

        adapter = new MyArryAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.AdaptView, CustomView.multipleData.ToList());
        listView.Adapter = adapter;


        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        pb.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}
```

Comment: Items like assignment of the adapter have to be done on the UI thread, but the creation of your adapter does not, not sure what AccessFiles() does, but is it UI context dependent?, etc.....

Comment: no it just checks if file exist or not if does not exist it will write the file to filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Try this (my apologies, I don't have time to test it at the moment as I'm looking through questions while I wait for builds to finish):

```
public async void OnAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Dodo()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    RunOnUIThread(AssignDodoAdapter());
}

void Dodo()
{
    AdRequest adRequest = new 
 AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice(AdRequest.DeviceIdEmulator).Build();
    adView.LoadAd(adRequest);
    AccessFiles();
    adapter = new MyArryAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.AdaptView,  CustomView.multipleData.ToList());
}

void AssignDodoAdapter()
{
    listView.Adapter = adapter;
    adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    pb.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}
```

Note: I'm assuming that adapter, listview etc are exposed as fields that may be referenced, as in your code sample.

OnAnimationEnd() should be be marked async. It should run the code in Dodo() on a background (non-UI) thread allowing other events to be handled on the UI thread, but because it is awaited, it will not continue to the next code block. Once the Task is complete it should then run the code in AssignDodoAdapter() on the UI Thread.